# Docker Python API Update method generates TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, docker, typeerror

The Docker SDK for Python documents that the Container object class "container" supports an "update" method, described as follows in docs:

---

**update**(**kwargs)
Update resource configuration of the containers.

Parameters:
blkio_weight (int) – Block IO (relative weight), between 10 and 1000
cpu_period (int) – Limit CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) period
cpu_quota (int) – Limit CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) quota
cpu_shares (int) – CPU shares (relative weight)
cpuset_cpus (str) – CPUs in which to allow execution
cpuset_mems (str) – MEMs in which to allow execution
mem_limit (int or str) – Memory limit
mem_reservation (int or str) – Memory soft limit
memswap_limit (int or str) – Total memory (memory + swap), -1 to disable swap
kernel_memory (int or str) – Kernel memory limit

restart_policy (dict) – Restart policy dictionary

- Restart the container when it exits. Configured as a dictionary with keys:

  - Name: One of on-failure, or always.
  - MaximumRetryCount: Number of times to restart the container on failure.
  - For example: {"Name": "on-failure", "MaximumRetryCount": 5}

---

[reference in docker python api doc](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html)

When attempting to use this:

```
client = docker.from_env()
for container in client.containers.list():
    restart_policy = {'restart_policy',{'MaximumRetryCount': 4, 'Name': 'on-failure'}}
    container.update(restart_policy)
```

I encounter the error:

```
restart_policy = {'restart_policy',{'MaximumRetryCount': 4, 'Name': 'on-failure'}}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Guidance as to how to formulate the request appreciated please!

Comment: You have mentioned that restart_policy (dict) – Restart policy dictionary. And in the code restart_policy is a ```set``` and not ```dict```. May be you meant - ```restart_policy = {'restart_policy': {'MaximumRetryCount': 4, 'Name': 'on-failure'}}```

Comment: Thanks Ram, when I update as suggested the return error is as follows:   

`TypeError: update() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`   

Rgds..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass that parameter as a named parameter inside the function call:

```py
container.update(restart_policy={'Name': 'on-failure', 'MaximumRetryCount': 4})
```

If you need it as a separate dictionary for some reason, you need to pass that dictionary using the `**kwargs` syntax:

```py
kwargs = {
  'restart_policy': {
    'Name': 'on-failure',
    'MaximumRetryCount': 4
  }
}
container.update(**kwargs)
```

With a comma instead of a colon, `{a, b}` creates a Python `set`, where `{'a': b}` creates a `dict`.  Without the `**`, `function(args)` passes the dictionary as a positional parameter, where `function(**args)` expands the dictionary to pass named parameters.